# What does two stars mean in front of a switch statement

Tags: go, pointers

I am studying an existing go codebase and I see code like this

```
        switch v := value.(type) {
        case **model.User:
             // do something
        case **model.Session:
            // do something
        }
```

What does the `**` mean in front of each type check.  Does it mean pointer to a pointer ? makes my head spin, or is there something more simple ?

Answer (score 1):

A `*` in Go is a [pointer](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types). There is nothing special about `**`, it just means a pointer to a pointer.

This is checking if `value` is one of:

- a pointer to a pointer to a `model.User`
- a pointer to a pointer to a `model.Session`

Passing a `*x` to a function is fairly standard when the function needs to modify `x`. In this case, `x` is one of `*model.User` or `*model.Session`.

Comment: is there any particular scenario why someone would write code like this, coming from a non-pointer language I would say this is unnecessary complexity and bad code

Comment: It depends on how `value` is passed around. For example, it might be that way to pass as an argument and let the function modify the underlying pointer. You'd have to take it up with the authors.

Comment: thanks for that, I think it is modifying the pointer.  Is this some kind of pattern ?

Comment: Passing `*x` to a function that needs to modify `x` is pretty standard in pointer languages, yes.

Comment: Same, passing `**x` is standard is the function needs to modify `*x`.